# Return value from sendMessage or alternate in unity webgl

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am using Unity WebGL for my project and want to communicate from browser JavaScript to C#. **One way** is to call C# function from JavaScript using **SendMessage**. I am easily making call using this code snippet in javascript:

```
gameInstance.SendMessage("MyObjectName","MyFunctionName",myParameter);
```

But there is a problem it is not returning any value. For getting a value I have to implement a separate function that run another function. Can I return value directly? Send Message docs clearly stating it don’ t return any value, so other than sendMessage is there any way available to get return value from directly function calling?

Comment: Maybe this one can help https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Comment: Yeah, I have already studied it but its didn't include return value related things.

Comment: You can try to change any property in myParameter to get info about something <thinking>

Comment: ?? How myParameter is passed to function for input not for return value.

Comment: Your parameter can be reference type. If you wanna just return any info about external process - pull this info into this class

Answer (score -1):

Use your custom class as a parameter - for example:

```
public class CustomData
{
    public string Input;
    public string Output;
}
```

...

```
CustomData data = new CustomData();
data.Input = "Something";
gameInstance.SendMessage("MyObjectName", "MyFunctionName", data);
//use data.Input inside MyFunctionName like a parameter
//change data.Output inside MyFunctionName
//use data.Output
Debug.Log(data.Output);
```

Comment: Are sure that it will work? i am using this line in javascrip side, not c#. gameInstance.SendMessage("MyObjectName", "MyFunctionName", data);

Comment: Not sure, just try it out)

Comment: As documented, only strings and numbers can be passed to SendMessage. There's not currently a way to receive values back from the function.